# Replace string with special character in Excel

Tags: text, replace, excel-formula

I want to partially mask names on excel after concatenating:

A1: David Goliath
B1 (output): Dav*******ath

Please help. I need the 1st three and and last 3 characters shown and the rest to be replaced by a special character. Since this formula will be applied on a long list, the length of names would vary.

Comment: What do you do in cases name and surname is shorter than 6 characters? What is the purpose? It is safer to add fixed number of `*` for all names.

Answer (score 1):

**Formula**

```
=LEFT(A1,3)&REPT("*", LEN(A1)-6)&RIGHT(A1,3)
```

**Picture**

[image: results]

**How it works**

This formula relies on string manipulation to grab the first 3 characters, last 3 characters, and a string of `*` in the middle.  This assumes that the entries are at least 6 characters long.  If you want it to work for less than 6, you would need to decide how to hide the middle.

The only real trick is knowing that the number of `*` you need is 6 less than the length of the string since you are taking 3 characters from the front and back.